# Grails 2.4.3 - Asynchronous Programming @DelegateAsync

Tags: grails, asynchronous

Suppose the following situation...

- I have to perform a process which takes a lot of time (about 1 hour)
  and I do not want the user of my application to wait until it ends.
- The business logic of this process is encapsulated in several services.

So:

```
class MyService{

    def myService2
    def myService3

    public doSomething(){ 
       myService2.doSomething()
       myService3.doSomething()
    }
}

class MyController{

    def myService

    def anAction(){
       myService.doSomething()
       redirect(action:'index')
    }
}
```

- I want the call to my service to be asynchronous.

I tried to create an asynchronous service as indicated by the Grails documentation, using **@DelegateAsync**.

```
class AsyncMyService {

    @DelegateAsync MyService myService

}

 class MyController{

    def asyncMyService

    def anAction(){
       asyncMyService.doSomething()
        .onComplete { List results ->
           println "completed!"             
        }
       redirect(action:'index')
    }
}
```

But I get the following error when compiling my application:

```
Caused by ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 
'MyService2$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f08a1b38' to equired type 'grails.async.Promise' 
for property 'myService2'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot 
convert value of type [MyService2$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f08a1b38] to required type 
[grails.async.Promise] for property 'myService2': no matching editors or conversion 
strategy found
```

Any ideas to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Umm... grails version? Java version? Those might help you get an answer.

Comment: Grails 2.4.3. Java 1.7.

Comment: Is it because myService2 and myService3 are not asynchronous? It could be that when the DelegateAsync transform attempts to create an async version of your myService, it fails because of these other dependencies. Try removing those services temporarily and see if it works as expected. If so, you may just have to create async versions of myService2 and myService3.

Comment: @BryanGCampbell I'll try this and tell you the result